# CakePHP: add new row for table as needed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp-1.3

I need to create a receipt thing.
User is able to create new product which is consist of various number of ingredients.

I'm using a table to layout the inputs, and on each row there is a select list of existing ingredient generated with the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Receipt.0.ingredient_id', array( 'label' => false,'div' => false, 'class' => ''));
```

which generated the following html

```
<select id="Receipt0IngredientId" class="" name="data[Receipt][0][ingredient_id]">
<option value="1">Ingredient B</option>
<option value="3">Ingredient B</option>
<option value="4">Ingredient B</option>
</select>
```

and another field to input the amount of the chosen ingredient needed.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Receipt.0.amount', array( 'label' => false,'div' => false, 'class' => '')); ?>
```

the thing is the kinds of ingredients will vary based on the the product and currently I'm using jQuery to add new rows when user clicked add new row button, but I dont know how to change the name value of each field
the jQuery code:

```
$("#addNewLine").click(function() {
      $('#add_ingredient tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#add_ingredient tbody>tr:last');
      return false;
    });
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to implement this. any help or suggestion would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using jQuery to add new rows when user clicked add new row button, but I dont know how to change the name value of each field

When you clone an element you can modify it before (or after) inserting it:

```
$('#add_ingredient tbody>tr:last').clone(true)
                                  .attr("name", "new name here")
                                  .insertAfter('#add_ingredient tbody>tr:last');
```

If you post some more detail, e.g., show the html before the change and then an example of what you'd like the new html to look like then I could offer some more detailed advice.

P.S. Are you talking about "receipts" or "recipes"?

Comment: it's receipts(formula). all I need to change is the name value of the newly added row e.g. name="data[Receipt][0][ingredient_id] count up the second index

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

First calculate number of select boxes in your html by using,

```
var count = $('select').size();
```

Then,
Add selectbox html as per need like,

```
$('body').append('<select id="Receipt'+count+'IngredientId" class="" name="data[Receipt]['+count+'][ingredient_id]">
<option value="1">Ingredient B</option>
<option value="3">Ingredient B</option>
<option value="4">Ingredient B</option>
</select>');
```

Comment: the thing is all the options are generated from database and I'm not aware of the options in advance.